# What does $x^{-}$ mean?

Tags: statistics

When I was reading "Probability and Statistics" (DeGroot & Schervish, 4th ed, p.110), I came across this equation: $$\Pr (X < x) = F(x^{-})$$ What does $x^{-}$ mean? I've seen $x^{10}$ or $x^{-10}$ before, but never this kind of things.

Comment: Limit from the left: $$F(x^-)=\lim_{t\to x,t<x}F(t)$$ Likewise, the limit from the right would be: $$F(x^+)=\lim_{t\to x,t>x}F(t)$$

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks a lot!